# Vertical Navigation Bar not working properly

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I am trying to make a navigation bar for the left side of my page but it is not working properly. The link color won't change to green, the hover feature doesn't work, and the background color for the menu only covers the links themselves instead from top to bottom of the page.

```css
ul.nav {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 30%:
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.nav li {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
{
ul.nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="x">x</a></li>
    <li><a href="x">x</a></li>
    <li><a href="x">x</a></li>
    <li><a href="x">x</a></li>
    <li><a href="x">x</a></li>
    <li><a href="x">x</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please update with your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two typos in your CSS:

```
width: 30%:
```

You put a colon at the end, not a semicolon, so every property in that rule after width is being ignored.

```
...
width:10%;
        {
ul.nav li a {
...
```

You accidently put an opening bracket ( **{** ) here rather than a closing bracket ( **}** ). That's causing all your rules after that to be ignored.

Comment: OP might also need to get rid of the `height:100%` rule for `ul.nav li`, otherwise a single `li` will span the entire height and only one will be visible (unless that's what they're going for, of course).